# Unable to locate JDBC data source 

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic, jndi

I have a query. My application is deployed using WebLogic server, where a JDBC data source is configured. The application config file is configured to pick up the JNDI name and make connectivity to connection pool at application startup. When there is no network connectivity, it fails to resolve the JDBC data source. On resuming network connectivity, we have to restart the server in order to get the JDBC data source working.

Is there any way to dynamically enable JDBC data source in WebLogic or to resolve it after a network failure once connectivity is back instead of restarting the server?

Comment: Are you defining the dataSource via web.xml and context.xml files?

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic does it automatically if you set the "initial connection" to 0 in Datasource connection pool. But you have to rewrite your application to periodically check, if the datasouce is UP or DOWN.